# How do I download Vimeo's video?

Tags: video, download, vimeo

I need to download Vimeo's video but I just can't find where to download them?

Comment: Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63590602/6075331, which is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

One can see below that there is a `Download` button, but you need to sign-in to download.

[image]

Some channels won't allow you to download, and in this case there will be no Download button available. [Keepvid.com](http://keepvid.com) will then do the job.

Comment: Hehe, how easy. I was looking for the download link inside the Video screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend `youtube-dl`

Project hompage: http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/

Github repo: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl

- open source
- feature rich
- great documentation
- cross platform (almost entirely written in python)
- supports over 400 video sites
- actively maintained (5k+ commits and counting)

It's awesome, you're missing out if you don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this site http://www.savevideo.me/ and here paste the link of video and just click on Download Button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[DownloadHelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/)** add-on for [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/).  works great!